# SH.exe crashes on windows 7

Tags: windows, sh

The sh.exe is crashing in windows 7. 
Even in compatibility mode  with win xp, this occurs.
The crash is not consistent.
This occurs when make clean or make command is given.

Comment: What is this "sh.exe"?

Comment: That is a .exe to make a virtual linux atmosphere in windows for compilation with gcc etc